# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function when called inside a select change function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, typeerror

Please check this, a question for jquery ui slider

Html

```
<div id="slider-term">
  <div id="custom-handle-term" class="ui-slider-handle"></div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
var handleTerm = $("#custom-handle-term");    
var slider = {      
    term: function() {
        $("#slider-term").slider({
        value: 2,
        min: 2,
        max: 24,
        create: function() {
        handleTerm.text($(this).slider("value") );
        },
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            handleTerm.text(ui.value);
        }
    });
    },
    termSetMin: function() {
        $("#slider-term").slider("option", "min", 6);
    }
}

slider.term();
```

When I call `slider.term()`, it works fine.

But when I tried to call `slider.termSetMin()` inside a select change function

```
$('#product').change(function() {
   slider.termSetMin();
});
```

This error shows

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function
```

What causes this? And how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: If the error really is `$(...).slider is not a function`, then `slider.termSetMin();` is not the line of code causing that problem.

Comment: Even if I call slider.term() inside a select change function, that error shows. But outside it works fine. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is loaded twice, just removed the other